# Recursive function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, recursion

I'm trying to solve the problem "is Subsequence"

> https://leetcode.com/problems/is-subsequence/

in kotlin. I decided to use recursion. The is the solution:

```
const val first = "abc"
const val second = "ahbgdc"

fun isSubsequence(first: String, second :String): Boolean {
    if(first.isEmpty())
        return true
    if(second.isEmpty())
        return false
    return subCheck((first.length).minus(1),(second.length).minus(1))
}

fun subCheck(s: Int, t: Int): Boolean {
    println("$s  $t")
    if(s == -1) return true
    if(t == -1) return false
    if(first[s] == second[t]) subCheck(s.minus(1),t.minus(1))
    return subCheck(s,t.minus(1))
}

fun main() {
    println(isSubsequence(first, second))
}
```

I've been struggling to find where the problem is since it always returns false with this input and when I tried to debug it I found that the value of s and t reach -1 and -1. however instead of returning true, the values of s and t change to 0 and -1.

this is the the output of the println statement:

```
1  4
1  3
1  2
0  1
0  0
-1  -1
0  -1
1  1
1  0
1  -1
2  4
2  3
2  2
2  1
2  0
2  -1
false
```

Comment: You're missing a return on the line `if(first[s] == second[t]) subCheck(s.minus(1),t.minus(1))`. Also, isn't `s - 1`, etc. more readable than `s.minus(1)`, etc.?

Comment: I didn't notice that the if statement needed a return. and yes the `s -1` is more readable, thank you